# Comprobación de Anagramas en C#

Tags: c#, anagramas

Un problema que me pide que compare dos cadenas de caracteres y que me diga si es anagrama o no, ejemplo roma y amor sería anagrama, el lenguaje es C#.

El problema es que necesito que cuando ingrese roma y amor me diga que es anagrama y cuando ingrese hola y roma aunque tengan la misma cantidad de letras me diga que no es anagrama porque las letras ingresadas no son iguales.

```
using System;

namespace comparaTO
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string palabra1;
            string palabra2;

            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la primera palabra a comparar");
            palabra1 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la segunda palabra a comparar");
            palabra2 = Console.ReadLine();
            
            if(palabra1.Equals(palabra2))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Las cadenas son anagramas");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Las cadenas no son anagramas");
            }
                        
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `.Equals(string)` verifica si ambas cadenas tienen el mismo valor. Roma y Amor, aunque tengan *las mismas letras ordenadas de una manera distinta*, no pueden ser consideradas iguales, por lo tanto el resultado es `false`. Tendrás que crear un algoritmo que verifique ambas cadenas tengan la misma cantidad de los mismos caracteres. Y pues, inténtalo, de lo contrario parece que nosotros haremos tu tarea, y no creo sea el objetivo de tu profesor

Comment: En tu código no hay intento de resolverlo, solo usas el método Equals y claramente no son iguales ROMA y AMOR. Intenta desarrollar la idea tu mismo y plantea lo que has intentado. Por lo pronto y como pura curiosidad te dejo cómo hacerlo [modificando una sola linea](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SRtxsy) usando Linq. Obviamente no es esto lo que quiere quien te haya mandado esta tarea, ya que si no sabes hacer eso tan sencillo, no creo que conozcas aún Linq.

Comment: Título = idea general. Cuerpo del mensaje = Detalles.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez en el ejemplo que pones lo que estas verificando es que ambas palabras sean palindromos, anagrama es algo diferente, un palindromo es un anagrama, pero un anagrama no necesariamente es un palindromo ej: roma, amor, ramo, omar, rmoa, mora y cualquier combinacion de estas 4 letras son anagramas entre ellas

Comment: @Japv Gracias por la observación. Definitivamente confundí palíndromo con anagrama, y bueno, la descripción del problema la verdad no ayuda nada con el contexto.

Comment: entonces es palindromo o anagrama? porque si es palindromo, las respuesas que te dieron estan todas mal...

Comment: @gbianchi el op dice anagrama claramente

Comment: Hola Dext, podrias decir si las respuestas dadas te resultaron utiles y marcar como aceptada la q soluciono tu problema, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo una posible solución haciendo uso de **Linq** para comprobar si dos palabras son **anagramas**.

Según la **Wikipedia** una palabra es **anagrama** de otra si las dos tienen las mismas letras, con el mismo número de apariciones, pero en un orden diferente, por ejemplo:

sergio => riesgo

enrique => quieren

aretes => teresa

A continuación el código:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string resultado = "Las cadenas no son anagramas";
   string anagrama = "";

   Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la primera palabra a comparar:");
   string palabra1 = Console.ReadLine();

   Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la segunda palabra a comparar:");
   string palabra2 = Console.ReadLine();
        
   if(palabra1.Length == palabra2.Length)
   {
      anagrama = palabra1.ToLower().Intersect(palabra2.ToLower());

      if(anagrama.Count() == palabra1.Length)
      {
         resultado = "Las cadenas son anagramas";
      }
   }
    
   Console.WriteLine(resultado);                
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Lo primero que se hace aquí es declarar las **variables resultado** y **anagrama** ambas de tipo **string**. Posteriormente se le pide al usuario que ingrese las palabras a comprobar si son o no **anagramas**. Después se pregunta si ambas cadenas tienen la misma longitud, ya que de no tener la misma longitud se descarta que sean **anagramas**. En caso de que ambas palabras tengan la misma longitud entonces se procede a usar el **operador de conjuntos Intersect** el cual devuelve una lista con los elementos o caracteres en común que tienen ambas palabras, posteriormente se compara la cantidad de elementos que tiene esta lista con la longitud de cualquiera de las palabras introducidas por el usuario(yo hice la comparación con **palabra1**, pero pudo haber sido también **palabra2**) y si tienen la misma longitud pues ambas palabras son **anagramas**.

Para hacer uso de **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

En esta solución usamos arrays: se convierten las palabras a arrays de caracteres, los ordenamos y los comparamos. Si son iguales se trata de anagramas en caso contrario no lo son, tampoco lo son si las palabras tienen diferente longitud.
Por lo que veo si consideras anagramas las palabras iguales.

```
namespace comparaTO {

class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string palabra1;
            string palabra2;
            char[] lista1;
            char[] lista2; 
            bool son = false;  //Por defecto no son anagramas
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la primera palabra a comparar");
            palabra1=Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la segunda palabra a comparar");
            palabra2=Console.ReadLine();
            //Solo se comprueba si tienen la misma longitud
            if(palabra1.Length == palabra2.Length){
                lista1 = palabra1.ToCharArray(); //Convertimos a array
                lista2 = palabra2.ToCharArray();
                Array.Sort(lista1);  //ordenamos los arrays
                Array.Sort(lista2);
                palabra1 = string.Join("",lista1); //convertimos a cadena
                palabra2 = string.Join("",lista2);
                son =  palabra1 == palabra2;  //comparamos
            }
            if (son)
               Console.WriteLine("Las cadenas son anagramas");
            else
               Console.WriteLine("Las cadenas NO son anagramas");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```